# How to insert value in option - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I'm newbie with AngularJS

I'm not able to get the correct tag "value" of each option

http://jsfiddle.net/gislef/x8mcrkju/1/

In the DOM, options, displaying this value = "object: 3" value = "object: 4" etc.

```
...     
"SituacaoTributaria": [{
            "value": 00,
            "situacao": "00 - Tributada Integralmente"

        }, {
            "value": 10,
            "situacao": "10 - Tributada com Cobrança de ICMS por ST"

        },
...
```

We report the value select in each array, but does not print on values in each option

I've seen similar questions and I tried to solve but I still can not solve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed using "track by"

```
ng-options="r.regime for r in data track by r.id"
```

Answer (score 0):

The pattern for `ngOptions` is `thing.value as thing.displayName for thing in things`.

So...

```
<select ng-model="selected.regime" ng-options="r.value as r.regime for r in data">
```

But I suggest keeping it as a selection of objects.  That way, you have access to selected properties later on.

Further reading: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions